# Import Webdrivemanager not resolved

Tags: selenium

Tried adding this maven dependency in Selenium for Webdrivermanager

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But still it complains as not resolved.

It was not automatically importing the package , so tried adding `import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;` manually.

Still the issue is there.

Checked the previous post as of Apr 2020 , but not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.ChromeDriverManager;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.FirefoxDriverManager;
```

You can try to import specifically WebDriver managers.

And also could you please try older versions of **bonigarcia** like;

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
   <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.4</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Tried the above solution and it resolved that error.But later giving this error  “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils . Then tried including commons.io in pom.xml and this issue was resolved. But then now getting error like Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-5', revision: 'b3a0d621cc'. My Chrome version is 83.0.4103.61 and is the latest. Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: Please try this --> ChromeDriverManager.getInstance(CHROME).version("83.0.4103.61").setup();